# Typeset colored terminal output using minted

Tags: color, highlighting, minted, input-encodings, pygments

I need to reproduce the output of a command in a LaTeX document. The command uses ANSI escape codes to produce colored output.

I'd like to use `minted`, but using `\inputminted{shell}{coloredoutput}` produces the following error:

```
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.2 ^^[
       \PY{o}{[}01\PY{p}{;}31m^^[\PY{o}{[}Kt^^[\PY{o}{[}m^^[\PY{o}{[}K^^[\PY...
```

To reproduce, create colored output by running

```
grep --color=always . <(echo test) > coloredoutput
```

and then compiling the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\inputminted{shell}{coloredoutput}
\end{document}
```

You will need `-shell-escape`.

The error, I imagine, is due to pygments not properly parsing the color codes. How do I force make it parse them properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. Currently, Pygments (which `minted` uses internally) performs all coloring based on styles, not based on color information passed to it.  There has been a [feature request for something like this](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/issue/770/support-ansi-ecma-48-color-coded-text) since 2012, but it doesn't appear that any progress has been made.

You have a couple of options. You could look through the existing Pygments styles to see if one of them is close enough to what you need.  If not, you could consider [creating a custom style](http://pygments.org/docs/styles/).  Otherwise, a high-resolution screenshot may be the simplest solution.

Comment: The feature request URL is broken. Perhaps [this alternative](https://github.com/chriskuehl/pygments-ansi-color) might be helpful.